# How to use regular expressions in "in" python function

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm ussing Python 'in' function to check if a little string is inside another bigger string. The problem is what next:

```
word1 = 'log'
word2 = 'log_enable'
string = ['parent_log', 'parent_log_enable']

for e in string:
    if word1 in e:
        print 'here we have the word'
```

So, obviously, "here we have the word" will be printted twice. I want to know if a regular expression can be used in 'in' function and, in this case, which one should I use to get the correct output?

Thanks, regards.

Mike.

Comment: `in` does not support regular expressions. Just use the `re` module directly.

Comment: If you are only testing two possibilities, you could start testing for the longer one.

Comment: And why would it 'obviously' be printed twice? Your code tests two strings, both strings match. What would the expected outcome be? You never test `word2` here.

Comment: Yeah, I never test word2 but 'log' is in every word of 'string' vector, so the print is going out twice (twice because string vector has two cells)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a regular expression with `in`. Just use the module directly to *replace* `in`:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'log(?:_enable)?')

for e in string:
    if pattern.search(e):
        print 'here we have the word'
```

Here the pattern checks for `log` optionally followed by `_enable`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `in` by itself to achieve what you want.

If you wanted to use `in` because it's more succinct, **list comprehensions** may be what you want.

I'll build on Martijn's answer

```py
import re
p = re.compile(r'log(?:_enable)?')
# Check if any match
any(p.search(s) for s in ['parent_log', 'parent_log_enable']) 
# Result: True

# Get all matches
[s for s in ['parent_log', 'parent_log_enable'] if p.search(s)] 
# Result: ['parent_log', 'parent_log_enable']
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a interesting solution but Martijn's code is better for mi script. Thanks again

Comment: Do not use a list comprehensions when a generator expression will do. You execute `p.search()` on all inputs first, *then* have `any()` test the results. That defeats the point of `any()`.